# MediaPlayer setLooping(true) doesn't work

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, textureview

I use MediaPlayer for displaying video. I need to loop it. I use native method setLooping(), but it doesn't work. Video finished and that's all. Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);

        TextureView videoViewFullScreen = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.video_screen);

        path = getIntent().getExtras().getString(SettingsActivity.FILE_PATH);
        cycle = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(SettingsActivity.CYCLE);

        position = getIntent().getIntExtra(FullScreenActivity.POSITION, -1);

        videoViewFullScreen.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

                final Surface surf = new Surface(surface);
                try {
                    mediaPlayerFullScreen = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayerFullScreen.setDataSource(path);
                    mediaPlayerFullScreen.setSurface(surf);
                    if (cycle) {
                        mediaPlayerFullScreen.setLooping(true);
                    }

                    mediaPlayerFullScreen.prepareAsync();

                    mediaPlayerFullScreen.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            if (position != -1) {
                                Log.d("Position", "Position Full " + position);
                                mediaPlayerFullScreen.seekTo(position);
                            }

                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                mediaPlayerFullScreen.stop();
                mediaPlayerFullScreen.release();
                mediaPlayerFullScreen = null;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayerFullScreen != null) {
            mediaPlayerFullScreen.stop();
            mediaPlayerFullScreen.release();
            mediaPlayerFullScreen = null;
        }
    }
```

I looked all similar questions and tried all answers that find here, but none of them helped me. 
I have Android version 4.4.2, Firmware version 4.5, Kernel version 3.3.0
Could someone help me? Is there another way to loop video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find replacement for setLooping(true), this works for me:

```
                    mediaPlayerFullScreen.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mediaPlayerFullScreen.reset();
                        try {
                            mediaPlayerFullScreen.setDataSource(path);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mediaPlayerFullScreen.setSurface(surf);
                        mediaPlayerFullScreen.prepareAsync();

                        mediaPlayerFullScreen.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```